# Convert Colon-Separated Path to NSURL

Tags: nsurl

Is there a straight-forward way to convert a colon-separated path (i.e. "Macintosh HD:Users:stuarttevendale:Documents:DBTest.db") to an NSURL (i.e. "file://localhost/Users/stuarttevendale/Documents/DBTest.db")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such paths are HFS-style paths. Use `CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath()` with `kCFURLHFSPathStyle`.

Comment: @Julian, so should be anything which provides an HFS-style path. If you're encountering this problem, can I ask why/how you have an HFS-style path that you need to convert? Anyway, deprecated doesn't mean you **must** stop using it right away. If you have a need and the deprecated API is the only thing that solves it, then keep using it for as long as it works. Just consider yourself warned that it could stop working or even go away eventually.

Comment: Yeah, sure, deprecation is not deletion, no question. But I don't like deprecations and warnings in my project ;) I no, HFS is old fashioned and I really dislike it, but the Scripting Bridge interface of MS Word is still using these paths :( I hope the interface of the upcoming version will be better